# Exit from Java Callable if Exception occured

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

I am using ExecutorService and Callable in Java. The class implementing Callable does some IO work on the filesystem. How do I stop the execution of a callable and exit from it, if an Exception occurs?

This is an example class implementing Callable that has two methods, foo1() and foo2()

```
public class MyCallable<Object> implements Callable<Object> {
    public Object call() throws IOException, SQLException {
        // method 1 , could throw IOException
        foo1();
        // method 2 , could throw SQLException
        foo2();
        return null;
    }
}
```

This is the example execution service class. It can deal with exceptions occurred during the parallel processing through the futures object.

```
public class MyExecutorService {
    ExecutorService listProcessor;
    listProcessor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
    List<Callable<Object>> callableTodo = new ArrayList<Callable<Object>>();

    // add the callables to the todo list
    callableTodo.add(new MyCallable<Object>());
    callableTodo.add(new MyCallable<Object>());

    // start the threads
    List<Future<Object>> futures = listProcessor.invokeAll(callableTodo);
    listProcessor.shutdown();
    listProcessor.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS);

    // futures now holds possible exceptions
    for (Future<Object> future : futures) {
     try {
        future.get();
     } catch (ExecutionException e) {
         // process the exception
     }
    }
}
```

But I would like to immediately let the MyCallable stop if for example a IOException occurs in foo1(), and not let it continue with foo2();

EDIT: Also, if an unchecked exception such as a RuntimeException occurs in foo1(), MyCallable also needs to stop.

Comment: That's what will happen. If foo1 throws an exception, the call() method will immediately stop executing. What makes you think it would not stop?

Comment: It is not evident from my original question, but would Runtime exceptions also bubble up and force the Callable to stop?

Comment: Yes, of course. What other thing could happen? You should really learn the basics of exceptions before using concurrency, which is a very, very, very complex matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The signature of `Callable<V>`'s [`call`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html#call--) method is

`V call() throws Exception`

and its description is

> Computes a result, or throws an exception if unable to do so.

In other words, just don't catch the `IOException`.  If you don't catch it, then execution stops and the exception is passed up a level.

Note: this only works for non-RuntimeExceptions if the method is marked as throwing an exception type, which `call` is marked as doing because it's declared as `throws Exception`.

As you're already aware, `Future`'s `.get` method will throw an [`ExecutionException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutionException.html) if the `Callable` throws an exception.